# Property 'moment' does not exist on type 'StaticRenderFunctions'.ts(2339

Tags: datatables, angular8, angular-datatables

I'm trying to use [datetime plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/datetime) with [datatables-angular](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) to render the format of Date time inside the data table :

```
:
:
 columnDefs: [

     {  targets:3,render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment( 'Do MMM YYYYY' ) },
```

but the Angular data table does not recognize the .moment function because I didn't download datatime plugin I'm wondering of how could I download this plugin by npm, or how could I use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution without downloading [datetime plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/datetime)

simply what I did is below :

```
columnDefs: [
  {  targets:9,render:function(data){
 var dt=new Date(data);
 return dt.getFullYear() + "/" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate();
}},
]
```